# UK Family Permit Application and Supporting Documents

Tags: uk, family, eu-citizens, palestine-citizens

I filled the application of the UK family permit on visa4uk.fco.gov.uk

My wife and I have been married for two months, and we'd like to visit our friends in the UK. My wife is a Spanish citizen and I am Palestinian. We are living together in Palestine (the lease is in my and her names) and we have a joint bank account with both our names. The marriage certificate is Palestinian.

We are not yet registered with the Spanish authorities as a married couple (I'm told that it isn't a requirement for the Family Permit application).

The application asks for info that shouldn't be required such as income and where we'll stay while in the UK. Nevertheless, I filled in that info.

I would like to submit the application along with this question for your review. Please advise accordingly. Some of the info will be hidden for privacy's sake.

I would like to know the list of documents I should provide and whether my wife should accompany me to the interview (submitting the documents and biometric data collection) or not.

How should we prove that she's traveling with me? Should I provide flight tickets? Or would a cover letter from her addressed to the UK authorities attached with the other documents suffice? And how would such a letter be written and signed/certified?

Please find attached the application as a PDF. There are comments in the file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnqmtp48bmsey5l/Visa4UK%20-%20Confirm%20Application_Redacted.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know the list of documents I should provide...

Since you are recently married, you will probably be suspected of a "marriage of convenience," but evidence that you live together should overcome that, so do include something showing that you live together.

Other than that, [all you need](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide) is your passports and your marriage certificate.  If the certificate is not in English (or Welsh!), it should be accompanied by a certified translation (as should your evidence of cohabitation).

> ...and whether my wife should accompany me to the interview (submitting the documents and biometric data collection) or not.

It is not necessary for your wife to accompany you.

> How should we prove that she's traveling with me? should I provide flight tickets? or would a cover letter from her addressed to the UK authorities attached with the other documents suffice? and how would such a letter be written and sighned\certified?

I once prepared an EEA family permit application for my mother in law, who was planning to use it for a short visit.  I do not remember whether we submitted copies of the flight reservations, but I suspect we did not, because I doubt we would have made the reservation before the permit had been approved.  A simple statement that you plan to travel together should suffice.  There's no need to have it certified.

Comment: I've seen refusals on the internet where the reason was the lack of evidence that the EEA-national will be traveling with her\his spouse. please advise.

Comment: @Palio please add some links to such refusals to your question and ping me by replying to this comment when you have done so.

Comment: cant find it on the web. but I read "I'm not satisfied the EU citizen will accompany you on your trip" something to that meaning

Comment: @Palio perhaps in those cases the application was misconceived, the EU citizen was in fact not going to accompany, and the refusal was proper.  Or perhaps the refusal was improper; at times the UK has seemed to have a policy of making clearly improper refusals for one reason or another.  All I know is that the successful application I prepared for my mother in law did not include any evidence beyond the statements elicited by the application questions themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I got the family permit by mail earlier today.

I did not get an email saying I'll get it today though. I just got a phone call from aramex.

I sent with the application,  the marriage certificate, a lease agreement showing my and my wife's names, screenshots of past conversations, my wife's tarjeta sanitaria and her passport. (All copies) no idea why they didn't accept the originals, maybe it's different for other people though so take your originals please.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is mixed, one place you are asking for family permit and also mentioning that you need to visit UK. A permit is only issued when you are allowed to work, study or you are here for business purposes and that is referred as British Resident Permit or BRP.

If you are applying from Palestine, I doubt you might have an embassy there, just make sure what documents you submit should be in English, if they are translated in any other language they need to be translated into english and certified as true copies of the original.

And asking about your income is not an un-necessary question, all countries ask this, that is the sole purpose upon which they grant you visa entry into any country, they don't want someone to end up permanently in their country. So you have to clearly mention your source of income, whatever that is.

Always refer to www.gov.uk website for complete lists of documents that need to be submitted along with the application.

Comment: The EEA family permit allows one to work, but they're also issued for short-term visits.  The income question *is* improper because European Union freedom of movement does not depend on income.

Comment: MO Khan the UK family permit and British Resident Permit are two different things. the family permit is there to complicate things for non-eea citizens trying to visit the UK with their EU citizen spouses.
the EEA regulations state that asking about income for a family permit in the case of a spouse is unnecessary. get your facts right please