# UK family permit. Why weren't the original documents accepted?

Tags: uk, eu, family, permits

I recently applied for a family permit as the spouse of an EEA citizen. More details are available at [UK Family Permit Application and Supporting Documents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106407/uk-family-permit-application-and-supporting-documents)

I made the application online at visa4uk.fco.gov.uk.

When I attended the appointment at the application center the original documents were not taken, only copies (scanned at the center) were taken. Today I received an email confirming that the application was received at Sheffield.

The email stated:

> Your online application has been received at the UK Decision Making Centre.  Your application is currently being prepared for consideration by an Entry Clearance Officer.
>
> If you have made a Settlement application (except for applications lodged in USA and Canada): you must ensure that your UK sponsor has sent all relevant supporting documentation to the UK Decision Making Centre in Sheffield.  The documents should be arranged in this order: application form and relevant Appendix* (See below); English language evidence; relationship documents; maintenance documents; accommodation documents.   If documents are not received a decision will be taken on the basis on the information that has been provided.
>
> If you have already had your supporting documents scanned in at the Visa Application Centre, or if you have already sent them in to us, please ignore the request for documents.
>
> Please note that UKVI aims to complete all Visit Visa applications within 15 working days and all Settlement Visa applications within 12 weeks of the application date.  If it is not possible to complete your application within this timeframe a member of our team will contact you to explain why.
>
> If you have paid for Priority Service, your application will be placed in front of the queue and assessed ahead of other non-priority visa applications.  As indicated in the terms of service, the amount paid for the priority service, as well as the visa fees, is not refundable if the visa application is refused or if the decision is delayed.
>
> We regret that we are unable to respond to enquiries asking about the status of any application. Any status enquiry should be made to the international enquiry service, details of which are on the GOV.UK website.  Staff at Embassies, visa processing centres and visa application centres cannot assist with visa enquiries.  You may also wish to view the current processing times for applications made in your country.
>
> A further email will be sent to you to confirm when your application has been assessed and dispatched.  If your application was made in a Visa Application Centre, the staff there will contact you when your documents are ready – please do not attend the Centre until you are requested to do so.
>
> Please note that you are advised not to purchase flight tickets until you have secured a visa for travel to the UK.
>
> *List of Appendices:
>
> Appendix 1 - Children / Other Dependants
>
> Appendix 2 - Spouse / Partner
>
> Appendix 4 - Pre-flight family members of Refugees
>
> Appendix 5 - Access Rights to Child
>
> Further information is also available on the UK visas and immigration website.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> UK Decision Making Centre

why weren't the original documents accepted?

PS: The only original document taken was my passport.

Thanks.

Comment: Third paragraph of the email says "If you have already had your supporting documents scanned in at the Visa Application Centre, or if you have already sent them in to us, please ignore the request for documents."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you provided originals and the centre took copies then they have seen the originals and are satisfied that they are authentic so they don't need them any more.

Comment: Well the interviewer didn't examine the originals. She just scanned them. A marriage certificate and a lease agreement. Also we're traveling together why are the documents sent to Sheffield any way!

Comment: The scanned versions are or will be looked at by someone at another time, not necessarily the jnterviewer. Sheffield is just where the document store is. It doesn't matter for electronic documents.